# Code contracts .net - alternatives

Tags: .net, code-contracts

Recently, I started to use [Code contracts for .net](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts). The idea of code contracts itself is great in my opinion, but the implementation is very unpleasant.

The main reasons I don't like it are:

- I can use only methods like `Contract.Require()` inside my procedures. `ContractAbbreviator`s have so many restrictions (like, I cannot put them in a separate assembly and I cannot use parameters) that it makes them less usable. There are no attributes, and no extension methods, so my code becomes very verbose. For example, if I just want to check that my return value of type `Dictionary<string, string>`is not null, I need to add a monster such as `Contract.Ensure(Contract.Result<Dictionary<string, string>> != null)`. It's not even readable.
- The static analyzer makes so many false alarms that I spend more time shutting it up than fixing actual problems.
- It is extremely slow. Even though it has some cache, it takes a few minutes to analyze even a small project, and that makes it useless for incremental fixing. It just takes too long.
- There are bugs in `ccrewriter`—it cannot chew half of assemblies, and it cannot survive .net 4.0 assemblies in the .net 4.5 runtime.
- There is runtime/static checker dualism. When I had just started I thought it was as simple as `Debug.Assert`—you just add them everywhere you feel you need. But it turns out that I need to prove everything to the static checker, which is advanced, for sure, but the checker is stupid sometimes and can't resolve many obvious code constructions (like `while`). And there's no instrument to just say to the analyzer "I know what I'm doing, just ignore this contract violation".
- You cannot relate conditions. For example, there is no way to explain to the static analyzer that if I check `string.NotNullOrEmpty` this includes `string != null`. Or if I have my own big procedure checking a file path, I cannot explain to the analyzer that it's for sure not null and not empty. The `ContractAbbreviator` attributes help a little bit, but all this verbosity goes there and it still looks dirty and stupid.
- Code contracts is being developed very slowly, and even though it is open source now, as far as I know the code base is in a bad state.

Is there any advanced alternative to Code Contracts which has fewer flaws?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know of any alternatives, but I perhaps I can address a few of your issues. I work in a team that uses contracts in all our code (~1000 modules) and run static analysis on every checkin as well as in VS.

- Code ugliness. We have separate interfaces for (almost) everything, along with abstract classes implementing those, joined by ContractClass and ContractClassFor attributes. The contracts are in the abstract ContractClassFor-classes which makes the actual implementation code almost free from code contracts.
- Static analyzer slowness is often due to not enough contracts, which forces the analyzer to do more work to find out if contracts can be broken.
- Static checker false Alarms. I have had a few, but not to an extent where it has become a problem. Again, if you have too few contracts, the static checker might not be able to complete the analysis in time.
- Static analyzer slowness can be debugged with these MSBuild options, which will show which methods take the most time to analyze.

  `msbuild myproject.sln /p:CodeContractsExtraAnalysisOptions="-show progress -stats=!! -stats slowMethods"`
- If you're certain that some condition always holds, then you can use Contract.Assume(condition) to instruct the static checker to assume that this is the case. Eg.

  `Contract.Assume(mystring != null && mystring != "")` or maybe just  `Contract.Assume(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mystring))`
- Regarding the use of Debug.Assert, I think it's a huge advantage to have the static checking instead of just making my application crash at the customers site. This way, I can remove the risk of having the application crash before I release the product. Maybe I misunderstand you, but I really don't think your comparison makes sense.